# mod_rewrite substitution not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with an Apache mod_rewrite.  My .htaccess file is located in "/posts".  Here's the contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ ?url=/posts/2014/1215A.html [QSA]
```

The incoming request is for "/posts/2014/1214A.html".  I want that request to be rewritten so as to be for, "/?url=/posts/2014/1215A.html".  It appears that the regular expression is matched.  The problem seems to be with the substitution.  I've actually had the whole thing working; but, I must have somehow messed something up.  Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?  Thanks.

```
   ... doug
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /posts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/posts/index
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ ?url=/posts/2014/1215A.html [QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Your code seems to differ from my non-working code in only 2 respects: (1) it adds the condition; and, (2) it changes the RewriteBase.  I'm not sure why the condition; but, it won't be invoked in any tested requests anyway.  So, substanitively, we differ only in the RewriteBase.  I think that the RewriteBase needs to be / in order for me to get a leading / in front of the ?.  As I mentioned, I have had this working and when it was working, it worked that way.   In fact, I don't really understand why it stopped working.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @User3311045 where is the htaccess located? and what happens when you go to the url?

Comment: .htaccess is located in /posts. Obviously, without the rewrite, the document at the location specified in the incoming request would simply be displayed. The purpose of the rewrite is to divert to a wrapper

Comment: htaccess is located in /posts. Obviously, without the rewrite, the document at the location specified in the incoming request would simply be displayed. The purpose of the rewrite is to divert to a wrapper which would instead wrap the document at the address specified in the query string.  When I enter a request, I get the wrapper.  That tells me that the regular expression is working.  What doesn't happen is that the document to be wrapped is not loaded. This suggests that the problem is most likely with the substitution rather than the regular expression.  Thanks.

Comment: Further testing strongly suggests that, the match is satisfied and the rewrite is triggered.  For whatever reason, it appears that the query string is not being appended.  Thanks.

Comment: I set this thing up on a dedicated server so that I could add logging with a LogLevel of 9.  I used a query string of "doug=jolley".  I'm posting the relevant log output in my subsequent comment.  As can be seen from the log info, the regular expression is matched, and the substitution is made.  mod_rewrite recognizes the presence of the query string; but, it doesn't append it. I'm at a loss.  Please see my logfile post.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.  Log file output is too big to post.